# How does Twitter's Website calculate how long a tweet was posted?

Tags: datetime, twitter, date-arithmetic

Here's a screenshot of my twitter feed (as of right now while me writing this Question).

[image]

Notice how the time is relative to **me**, right now? (those times *differences* are correct, btw)

How do they calculate that?

The reason I ask is that right now, i'm in Melbourne Australia. When I Remote Desktop to a server in the states, log in to twitter (using the SAME account) .. i get the same results!

At first, I thought they were calculating this based upon my account settings for Time Zone (which btw is set at +10 GMT)

[image]

But if that was the case, when I remote desktop to the server (which is in San Fran, CA) it should be showing different results in that RD terminal, right?

So how could they have coded this, please?

Comment: i guess, it uses JavaScript to fetch the local time & time zone and compare to the posting time of the tweet (respect to time zone, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter more than likely stores the date it was posted in UTC, it knows the time now in UTC (both on your machine and on the server).

Given that those date times are translated into the same timezone (UTC), it's a simple matter of taking the difference between the two times.

It's the same thing the Stack Exchange sites do to stamp the times for all the activities that you see.

As long as you're able to convert any representation of date time to UTC (which pretty much every API in existence has), this value is able to be computed as Twitter will push the UTC time down to the clients which then do the math (or do it on the server and pass the differences down); the settings that you see for UTC offset are when *absolute* times are displayed to you and you want them relative to your timezone.

Comment: yes, it's the difference between your time (in UTC) and the post time (in UTC) displayed back to you.

Comment: @Matt Maybe I don't understand the question, but the local time doesn't matter when looking at *relative* dates, as long as you're working with UTC, relative dates are easy to compute.

Comment: Right, exactly: the time difference is easy to compute when you normalize all times to UTC. I think I posted this before you really mentioned UTC, but it's the same: the time in Australia and the time in Greenwich, England _can_ be compared when all times are converted to UTC. In other words, this is the right answer: UTC is "universal", so all time comparisons are legal in UTC, regardless of the "real" time zone.

Comment: but this is all server side.. how does the server know of **my browser** time?

Comment: JavaScript : `var d = new Date()` and `d.getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: @Pure.Krome Two options, either a) the browser sends the time in UTC to the server, or b) the server sends the UTC time to the browser.  Either way, the times are always in UTC.

Comment: nod @casperOne ! Totally embarassing of me. it's nothing to do with browsers, clients, etc. it's all about having the data of the created tweet / SO question / some User Generated Content in the same format -> UTC. Frak! brain fart. :( Ta!!!!